# Deleting a bad answer after a remark

Tags: discussion

In this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/427402/how-to-read-the-value-of-this-capacitor/427408?noredirect=1#comment1064143_427408), I get a good reaction why the answer is not good, so I want to delete it. However, the persons who made the comments spend some time on it; should I immediately remove the answer or should I let them know to remove it? It feels bad to remove an answer including their comments 'immediately'.

Comment: Funnily enough, I was about to open a Meta question on this particular question too! Specifically on the use of the voting and commenting. As I had received negative words from one user about the way I had reacted tot he answer. As this is meta, is seems like a place to get your opinion of it! In my eyes, I downvoted the answer for the reason of it not being relevant to *that particular question*. I did acknowledge that it was good for other things though. I left a comment which explained my reasoning and thinking, so that the answer could be improved. You edited your answer.....

Comment: .....and I removed my downvote. I believe I went the right way about it, but apparently someone disagreed. I did acknowledge the good points of the answer, I gave my reasons for the downvote, and removed it once those reasons were addressed. In my opinion, the answer improved because of it. Because of that, in my opinion what I did was actually help rather than just being negative as someone seemed to think. I don't like downvoting things and leaving without saying why, and I would hope you appreciated the way I did things. Feel free to let me know your opinion on it!

Comment: @MCG Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @KevinKruse Yes, you are right, I updated the question.

Comment: The general stance on SE is that comments are not particularly important or valuable. Questions and answers are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The entire purpose of comments is to induce the poster to modify a post (question or answer). You have two options — either make modifications or don't. Modification could also mean deleting.

Don't worry about the comments. Comments that become irrelevant after modification will probably get deleted.